# Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument: CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, templates, aws-cloudformation

As I am trying to create a IAM Policy , I get this error while deploying the template in cloudformation:

```
JenkinsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - 
          Ref: "JenkinsRole"
  JenkinsPolicy:
   Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
   Properties:
      PolicyName: "JenkinsPolicy"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2020-01-29"
        Statement:
          - 
           Effect: "Allow"
           Action: 
             - "s3:GetObject"
             - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
             - "s3:PutObject"
             - "s3:DeleteObject"
           Resource: "*"
          - 
           Effect: "Allow"
           Action: 
             - "codedeploy:ListApplications"
             - "codedeploy:ListDeploymentGroups"
             - "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
             - "codedeploy:CreateDeployment"
             - "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig"
             - "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
             - "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
           Resource: "*" 
      Roles: 
        - Ref: "JenkinsRole"
```

Can someone help me with this, It would be quite hwlpful

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see your IAM role listed in the code. Additionally, there's an issue with your tabbing. I dunno if that's just from your copy/paste or if you actually do have it tabbed like that in the CFN template. But JenkinsPolicy is tabbed out and looks like a child of JenkinsInstanceProfile.

Notably, I don't see the version for policy documents you have listed, in the AWS documentation. They just have "2012-10-17", and "2008-10-17" as options
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_version.html

The following should hopefully fix your issue. Also, you didn't need two policy documents so I just put them in one.

```
JenkinsRole:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
  Properties:
    AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        -
          Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            Service:
              - "ec2.amazonaws.com"
          Action:
            - "sts:AssumeRole"
    Path: "/"
    RoleName: "JenkinsInstanceRole"
JenkinsInstanceProfile:
  Type: "AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile"
  Properties:
    Roles:
      - !Ref "JenkinsRole"
JenkinsPolicy:
   Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
   Properties:
      PolicyName: "JenkinsPolicy"
      PolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -  Effect: "Allow"
             Action: 
               - "s3:GetObject"
               - "s3:GetObjectVersion"
               - "s3:PutObject"
               - "s3:DeleteObject"
               - "codedeploy:ListApplications"
               - "codedeploy:ListDeploymentGroups"
               - "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
               - "codedeploy:CreateDeployment"
               - "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig"
               - "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision"
               - "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
             Resource: "*" 
      Roles: !Ref "JenkinsRole"
```